# Make a separate chapter for references and not as a section of last chapter

Tags: bibliographies, chapters

I'm really hoping someone can help me. I'm writing my masterthesis in a book environment. I am using apacite as my bibliography style, which was working fine (although not perfectly).Throughout the writing process I didn't pay much attention to it. But now suddenly, the references are part of my last chapter (the conclusion). [image: References]  I don't get what happened. Does someone know what to do? I'm not a very experienced Latex user, so would really appreciate a detailed explanation.

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
\chapter{Conclusions}\label{chapter:Conclusions}
\input{chapters/8Conclusion}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
\nocite{*}

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{The Dutch energy-label}\label{AppxA}
\input{Appendix/AppendixA.tex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That should not happen. The default definition of the bibliography in `book` creates a `\chapter*` that should be at the same level as your other chapters and does not appear in the table of contents. Can you show us a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) (follow the [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)), please?

Comment: Ahhh, OK, if you also load the `apacite` *package* (which you probably do) that could explain it...

Comment: You probably need the option `nosectionbib` (together with `numberedbib` if you want the bibliography numbered).

Answer (score 1):

The `apacite` *package* (which you probably load) has the option `nosectionbib` to make the bibliography appear as a `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`apacite` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) explains

> Moreover, `apacite` is configured such that it takes a section as default if it is in the main matter (signified by `\mainmatter`) of the document. In the back matter (`\backmatter`) the bibliography is put in a chapter. This is also the case if `\chapter` is defined but `\mainmatter` not. (Is this possible? Perhaps for reports?) Consequently, the `sectionbib` option is only useful in specific circumstances. The `nosectionbib` forces the bibliography to be a chapter, provided `\chapter` is defined. (I figured a `chapterbib` option would be a bit confusing, so I stuck with `nosectionbib`.)

That means you can avoid the option `nosectionbib` if you write your bibliography in the `\backmatter`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Lorem}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```